# Comparing strings read in line by line from a file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a very basic question. I am reading in a file in Matlab and I want to detect when a line says "occurence1". But I am getting "the" matrix dimention error. I am guessing matlab reads in some lines as matrices of numbers or so?

My data looks like this:

```
String2
occurence1
3.2 1.2
string3
occurence1
```

Should I cast tline to a string or something? I am well versed in Java, but I have some trouble with matlab's non defining of variables...

```
%open file with patterns
fid = fopen('filename.txt');

tline = fgetl(fid);

disp(tline);
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
    tline = fgetl(fid);


    if (num2str(tline)=='occurence1')

        disp(tline)
    end


end

fclose(fid);
```

Comment: The return of [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) is already a text string, so the `num2str` call is nonsensical. Also, use a string function, like [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html), to compare strings.

Comment: Also, as a general aside, it's far more useful to provide the *actual* error message and stack trace rather than saying "I've gotten the error"

Comment: Also also, your current implementation is never going to check the first line of your file.

Comment: Thank you, strcmp is what I was looking for!

Comment: Do you want to post strcmp as your answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the M-Lint message in the editor explains:

> The code compares two strings using either the equal to (`==`) or not
>   equal to (`~=`) relational operator. MATLAB software returns an error at
>   run time if the strings being compared are different lengths. Even if
>   MATLAB does not return an error when the code runs, it is likely that
>   this code is inefficient.

MATLAB's [`==`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html) returns a logical array where `A` and `B` are equal. Per the documentation, the inputs to `==` must be the same size unless one is a scalar (which is then expanded to the same size as the other array). Because your lines are not the same length, the equality check will fail when a line whose character length is not the same as `'occurence1'` is encountered. Because your algorithm skips the first row (you call `fgetl` outside of the comparison loop) and your second line is `'occurence1'`, you don't see the error until you get to your third line.

Rather than use `==`, utilize one of MATLAB's built in string comparison functions like [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) or [`strcmpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) to perform your logic check.

---

Additionally, while MATLAB is not statically typed, the outputs of the built-in functions are generally well documented. In this case, the documentation for [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) explains that the output is a string unless the line contains only the end-of-file marker. So the `num2str` call is unnecessary here.